# How to reference to a folder that is above Document Root, in PHP?

Tags: php, linux

I am still newbie and have my document root for my subdomain as below:

```
/home/myusername/public_html/lab2
```

and I want to include a file from `myusername/private` folder:

```
/home/myusername/private/config.php
```

What I tried was using something like this:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../../private/File.php');
```

..but that gives me this:

> /home/myusername/public_html/lab2/../../private/config.php

and when I try to use *dirname*

```
include (dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], 2) . "/private/config.php");
```

...it gives me only the last part:

> /private/config.php

Edit: I should clarify that I want to call this file from different directories through the site. For example: I am in `/home/myusername/public_html/lab2/academic/folder/test.php`, and I want to be able to call that specific `file.php` directly (i.e. without manually adjusting '../../' part for every page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use directly:

```
include('/home/myusername/private/config.php');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`realpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to get the complete path to the root of the folder you want to use. So if you're in `lab2` then you could use:

```
define("ROOT", realpath(__DIR__ . "/../");
define("ROOT_PRIVATE", realpath(ROOT . "/../private/");
include ROOT_PRIVATE . "/config.php";
```

I like to define folders I'm possibly going to use more than once. If you're only going to include this one file then you could just do (assuming you start in the `lab2` folder).

```
include realpath(__DIR__ . "/../../private") . "/config.php";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see my edit:

I should clarify that I want to call this file from different directories through the site. For example: I am in /home/myusername/public_html/lab2/academic/folder/test.php, and I want to be able to call that specific file.php directly (i.e. without manually adjusting '../../' part for every page).

Comment: Then you should use my first example. In your index or bootstrap file define ROOT then you can use `include ROOT_PRIVATE . "/config.php"` from anywhere. If you use the answer you selected as correct you **will** have to change it everywhere whenever you move servers.

Answer (score 1):

Please test below code:

```
echo realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../../private/File.php');
```